# Visual Studio didn't work from another directory

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 22 community on F:......
Then I had to rename my directory F:\ to E:\ (don't ask)
Now my visual studio installer can't find installed version (folder in on disk E:),
I can't launch visual studio from start panel etc.
Is there any way to restore this version, or I have to reinstall it. (my internet connection is super bad, and these 20+ gb are lethal)

Comment: Honestly, based on your description I'd just reinstall Windows from scratch - hideously complex software like VS really doesn't survive drive-letter renames.

Comment: As @Dai said, you'd probably be better reinstalling VS. Unless you can find every reference (shortcuts, windows registry, etc.) to the old folder and update it, you're going to find that one thing or another is not going to work. At best you'll likely end up with Visual Studio being unreliable. It can be a bit flaky even on a clean system!